# How can I stop Visual Studio from restoring old output files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2019

I keep finding old, obsolete files in the output folder of my Visual Studio project. I don't want these files there, as those folders get harvested by a related project that bundles those files into an installer.

Even after I deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders, they and their old contents are restored every time I build my solution and every time I open my solution in Visual studio.

The old files that I want to get rid of include things like old versions of dll's and folders with text files that were generated during a postbuild event that no longer exists.

It feels like there is some caching going on of which I can't find the source. A colleague of mine has no such problems, which increases my suspicion that this is some weird caching issue.

##### Things I've tried

- deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders
- cleaning the solution
- rebuilding the solution
- deleting the `.vs` folders at any level of the solution
- deleting `AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1x.0\ComponentModelCache`
- clearing `AppData\Local\Temp`
- cloning the containing git repository to a new folder and build from there

Comment: Your project may be referencing an assembly that itself has the old assembles as a dependency.

Comment: You might try the "Clean Solution" option -- also, are you using Git?

Comment: @VicF I did, forgot to mention it. Thanks.
I am using Git, yes. Though the `bin` and `obj` folders are excluded by a .gitignore.

Comment: @MatthewWatson but that wouldn't explain the folders with textfiles created through a postbuild event, right?

Comment: It is possible to turn up the level of output reporting when building. Doing so might give you a clue about what’s really happening.

Comment: Do you use some extensions which may collect some information? Have you checked the `.xxproj` file and does it include some related xml codes that point to generate or use some files? I agree with Vic, and please try to go to Tools > Options… > Projects and Solutions > Build And Run and set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Detailed`, and rebuild your project, then check the output window and search to see when and why the old files would be generated.